# Open running application from WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application I have a view that shows all the open windows and active applications on the PC, which I achieve with the following code:

```
  Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses(".");

  foreach (Process p in processlist)
  {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.MainWindowTitle))
    {
      TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
      item.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(item_MouseDoubleClick);
      item.Tag = p;
      item.Header = p.MainWindowTitle.ToString();
      TreeViewExternal.Items.Add(item);
    }

  }
```

1) How can I then show the running application when the tree view item is double clicked?
2) Is there a way of getting the  icon of the running application? For instance the VS icon next to the current window title of VS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "show the running application"? Do you mean that, when a tree view item is clicked, the main window of the selected application needs to gain focus?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, what I meant was that when a treeview item is clicked, the corresponding application should be showed, as in the Task Manager when "Switch To" is used. I did find the solution using the following code " IntPtr hwnd = p.MainWindowHandle;
      ShowWindowAsync(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
      SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);"

Answer (score 0):

For icon use this

```
Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. But as I am using WPF I need a Windows.Controls.Image from that icon. Any suggestions?